# Is there a way to declare suppresswarnings to the declaration of the method?

Tags: java, android, suppress-warnings

I have a static method which returns a value which is a [Magic Constant](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/02/new-magic-constant-inspection/).
Every time I access the method in my code I get a warning like this:

> Must be one of: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG

when I add `@SuppressWarnings("MagicConstant")` to the method where I want to access my method which returns either `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` the warning disappears.
But I have to add this suppresswarnings every time I want to use my static method. and this is annoying. Is there a way to add this warning directly to my method which returns one of the both values?

I tried this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("MagicConstant")
    public static int getToastDuration() {
        return ((statement) ? Toast.LENGTH_SHORT : Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
```

but this doesn't work.
I still have to add `@SuppressWarnings("MagicConstant")` to the method I want to use `getToastDuration()`

Example where I get this warning:

```
public void method() {
Toast.makeText(this,"text",Preferences.getToastDuration()).show();
}
```

The `Toast` class is the one of Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html

Comment: Can you please post an example of one of the methods where you're getting that warning?

Comment: Where are you getting this warning? From your IDE? If so, which one?

Comment: yes, Android Studio (IntelliJ)

Comment: Probably your only option is to entirely disable this warning in the IDE.

Comment: normally I want to have this warning only this special method should not fire this warning

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik This appears to be an interesting but half-baked extension from the IntelliJ people. It can identify that a particular method wants named numeric constants as inputs, but it apparently can't trace when they're supplied by a method call. With their system, it *should* be possible to annotate `getToastDuration()` with Javadocs listing its return types, but for now, I'm not seeing that option.

Comment: You can disable the warning in your entire project.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question, no, because the warning is being fired on the `makeText` invocation where the code analyzer isn't properly identifying that `Preferences.getToastDuration()` does in fact return one of the approved `int` values. Whichever tool is giving you the warning (IDEA?) is failing to look deep enough into the code. I don't think that the `MagicConstant` warning is standard, and I'd open a bug report for this.

Comment: it's android studio (IntelliJ);

Comment: its a warning from the IntelliJ IDE. look here: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/02/new-magic-constant-inspection/

Comment: I read the link from your question. The answer appears to be "this is a non-standard feature that isn't working correctly, so file a bug report".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this will work...

Wrap the affending method up inside another method:

```
class Preferences
{
    @SuppressWarnings("MagicConstant")
    public static int getToastDuration()
    {
        return _getToastDuration();
    }

    private static int _getToastDuration()
    {
        return ((statement) ? Toast.LENGTH_SHORT : Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't work because the warning is fired by `Toast.makeText`

Comment: @Simon, from reading your original question, I got the impression that the warning was coming from using `getToastDuration()` and not from `Toast.makeText`

Comment: first I thought the same but check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18314121/2180161

Comment: this is what in the android docs stands: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html

Comment: Seems strange that it would trigger a warning, as it's declared as an `int`. Well, if makeToast is the problem, wrap it up in a separate method and then only call the wrapper.